# Lose network connectivity when bringing up second NIC

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I currently have a CentOS 6.5 box with 4 NICs.

`eth0`, `eth2` and `eth3` all come up fine, however when I bring `eth1` up with an IP address, even on it's own, it causes complete network loss.

If I remove the IP and bring `eth1` up with the other NICs it works fine. Then adding an IP and restarting network services causes the network to lose connection again and requires a console connection to bring the interface down.

Is there anything that can be causing this on this particular NIC?

Configs for each NIC as below:

eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=3C:4A:92:11:11:11
IPADDR=192.168.228.225
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.228.254
DNS1=192.168.224.201
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
NAME="Management"
```

eth1

```
DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=no
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=3C:4A:92:00:00:00
IPADDR=192.168.223.225
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.223.254
DNS1=192.168.223.201
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
NAME="Production"
```

eth2

```
DEVICE=eth2
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=00:13:3B:00:00:00
NAME="Mirror Port Switch 1"
```

eth3

```
DEVICE=eth3
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=00:13:3B:11:11:11
NAME="Mirror Port Switch 2"
```

Comment: You've got 2 interfaces with 2 gateways. When `eth1` comes up, its gateway is probably taking over. Try removing the gateway from `eth1`.

Comment: @Patrick indeed it seems to have been the case. How can I have a gateway for the `192.168.228.0` network as well as the `192.168.223.0` network without it killing the connection?

Comment: If you have multiple gateways to the internet, how is the system supposed to know which one it should use? They're both equally valid. As for not killing `eth0`'s traffic, you need to use source based routing. It's been a while since I've done this on RedHat/Centos. Someone else can probably answer how this is configured on those distros.

Comment: @Patrick thanks for your help on this one. I managed to use persistent routes on `eth0` and use the gateway on `eth1` to get the desired result.

Comment: @lethalMango - please write up how you solved it. Other's can benefit from your issue. I seem to remember a couple of Q's in the past around multiple NICs and having this as a reference for these OP's would've been useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the original question comments this was caused by the multiple NICs having multiple gateways.

The solution to this specific problem was to remove a single default gateway from one of the NICs as below:

eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=3C:4A:92:11:11:11
IPADDR=192.168.228.225
PREFIX=24
DNS1=192.168.224.201
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
NAME="Management"
```

eth1

```
DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=no
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=3C:4A:92:00:00:00
IPADDR=192.168.223.225
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.223.254
DNS1=192.168.223.201
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
NAME="Production"
```

Persistent routes were then added to the NIC which had it's gateway removed:

/etc/sysconfig/network-script/route-eth0

```
192.168.111.0/24 via 192.168.228.254 dev eth0
192.168.222.0/24 via 192.168.228.254 dev eth0
```

The alternative I did find that resolved the network inaccessibility issue was by adding the `METRIC=x` line to NIC configs, however this did not resolve other network issues such as internet access.

Answer (score 0):

First edit this file:

```
$ vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
```

Then change ONBOOT to yes:

```
ONBOOT=yes
```

Then restart network, it will works fine.